# Appending Child Fails without Exception

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a JSON file that stores an array of objects. In the object, I have a property named `url` that stores the URL to a YouTube video. Once I fetch the JSON file and loop over the objects I am creating an `<iframe>` that sets the `src` to the `url` property. Here is the method I am using:

```js
const update = (information, selector) => {
    const parent = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (!information) {
        const rootParent = parent.parentNode;
        rootParent.remove();
        return
    }

    parent.querySelector('h4').innerText = information.title;
    parent.querySelector('h6').innerText = information.dateFormatted;

    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.setAttribute('height', '315');
    iframe.setAttribute('width', '560');
    iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
    iframe.setAttribute('src', information.url);
    parent.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

The issue is that the first call to the method works fine, but after the second iteration when it makes the call again it fails on the `parent.appendChild` line.

If I setup a try/catch and setup a breakpoint in the catch, the catch never gets fired. It isn't even being hit if I add a `debugger` statement to it.

What could be causing this and more importantly, why isn't the debugger being triggered?

Comment: setAttribute only sets the html element's attributes like 'class', 'id', 'title' etc. To access styling use `iframe.style.width = '560px';` Idk if that solves anything for you, but give it a try

Comment: How are you calling `update`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @Unmitigated - in a for/next loop, e.g. `for (let i = 0; i < records.length; i++) { 
  update(records[i], `record${i}`)
}`